# Get a file from an ASPX webpage using Python

Tags: python, asp.net

I'm trying to download a CSV file from this site, but I keep getting an HTML file when I'm using this piece of code (which used to work until a few weeks ago), or when I'm using wget.

```
url = "http://.....aspx"

file_name = "%s.csv" % url.split('/')[3]
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
f = open(file_name, 'wb')
meta = u.info()
file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)

file_size_dl = 0
block_sz = 8192
while True:
    buffer = u.read(block_sz)
    if not buffer:
        break

    file_size_dl += len(buffer)
    f.write(buffer)
    status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. / file_size)
    status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
    print status,
```

How can I get this file again with Python?

Thank you

Comment: Solved by using the Requests library instead of urllib2.

Comment: put it in the answer section and just accept it so that if someone else faces the same problem then you can lead them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by using the Requests library instead of urllib2:

```
import requests

url = "http://www.....aspx?download=1"

file_name = "Data.csv"
u = requests.get(url)

file_size = int(u.headers['content-length'])
print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)

with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in u.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
        if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
            f.write(chunk)
            f.flush()
f.close()
```