# Python - downloading a CSV file from a web page with a link

Tags: python, csv, web, download, session-cookies

I am trying to download the CSV files from [this page](https://www.paoilandgasreporting.state.pa.us/publicreports/Modules/DataExports/DataExports.aspx), via a python script.

But when I try to access the CSV file directly by links in my browser, an agreement form is displayed. I have to agree to this form before I am allowed to download the file.

The exact URLs to the csv files can't be retrieved. It is a value being sent to backend db which fetches the file - e.g `PERIOD_ID=2013-0`:

> https://www.paoilandgasreporting.state.pa.us/publicreports/Modules/DataExports/ExportProductionData.aspx?PERIOD_ID=2013-0

I've tried `urllib2.open()` and `urllib2.read()`, but it leads to the html content of agreement form, not the file content.

How do i write a python code which handles this re-direct and then fetches me the CSV file and let me save on disk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my suggestion, for automatically applying the server cookies and basically mimicking standard client session behavior.

(Shamelessly inspired by @pope's answer [554580](https://stackoverflow.com/a/554580).)

```
import urllib2
import urllib
from lxml import etree

_TARGET_URL = 'https://www.paoilandgasreporting.state.pa.us/publicreports/Modules/DataExports/ExportProductionData.aspx?PERIOD_ID=2013-0'
_AGREEMENT_URL = 'https://www.paoilandgasreporting.state.pa.us/publicreports/Modules/Welcome/Agreement.aspx'
_CSV_OUTPUT = 'urllib2_ProdExport2013-0.csv'


class _MyHTTPRedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):

    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        print 'Follow redirect...'  # Any cookie manipulation in-between redirects should be implemented here.
        return urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)

    http_error_301 = http_error_303 = http_error_307 = http_error_302

cookie_processor = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor()

opener = urllib2.build_opener(_MyHTTPRedirectHandler, cookie_processor)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

response_html = urllib2.urlopen(_TARGET_URL).read()

print 'Cookies collected:', cookie_processor.cookiejar

page_node, submit_form = etree.HTML(response_html), {}  # ElementTree node + dict for storing hidden input fields.
for input_name in ['ctl00$MainContent$AgreeButton', '__EVENTVALIDATION', '__VIEWSTATE']:  # Form `input` fields used on the ``Agreement.aspx`` page.
    submit_form[input_name] = page_node.xpath('//input[@name="%s"][1]' % input_name)[0].attrib['value']
    print 'Form input \'%s\' found (value: \'%s\')' % (input_name, submit_form[input_name])

# Submits the agreement form back to ``_AGREEMENT_URL``, which redirects to the CSV download at ``_TARGET_URL``.
csv_output = opener.open(_AGREEMENT_URL, data=urllib.urlencode(submit_form)).read()
print csv_output

with file(_CSV_OUTPUT, 'wb') as f:  # Dumps the CSV output to ``_CSV_OUTPUT``.
    f.write(csv_output)
    f.close()
```

Good luck!

### [Edit]

On the *why* of things, I think @Steinar Lima is correct with respect to requiring a session cookie. Though unless you've already visited the `Agreement.aspx` page and submitted a response via the provider's website, the cookie you copy from the browser's web inspector will only result in another redirect to the *Welcome to the PA DEP Oil & Gas Reporting Website* welcome page. Which of course eliminates the whole point of having a Python script do the job for you.

Comment: Nice solution! This will indeed work without having to visit the site when the session times out.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie. You can find this by using Chrome's *Inspect element* option in the context menu, or by using Firefox and the [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) extension.

**With Chrome:**

1. Right-click on the webpage (after you've agreed to the terms) and select *Inspect element*
2. Click *Resources* -> *Cookies*
3. Select the only element in the list
4. Copy the *Value* of the `ASP.NET_SessionId` element

**With Firebug:**

1. Right-click on the webpage (after you've agreed to the terms), and click *Inspect Element with Firebug
2. Click *Cookies*
3. Copy the *Value* of the `ASP.NET_SessionId` element

In my case, I got `ihbjzynwfcfvq4nzkncbviou` - it might work for you, if not you need to perform the above procedure.

Add the cookie to your request, and download the file using the `requests` module (based on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22840614/835002) by [eladc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1761782/eladc)):

```
import requests

cookies = {'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'ihbjzynwfcfvq4nzkncbviou'}
r = requests.get(
    url=('https://www.paoilandgasreporting.state.pa.us/publicreports/Modules/'
         'DataExports/ExportProductionData.aspx?PERIOD_ID=2013-0'),
    cookies=cookies
)

with open('2013-0.csv', 'wb') as ofile:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        ofile.write(chunk)
        ofile.flush()
```

Comment: setting the ASP cookie retrieves the page HTML content and not the CSV download output.

Comment: @user3602491 This does indeed work, but you may have to find your own cookie value. I've tried it myself, and the csv was downloaded with no hassle.